# Prevent nodemon from restarting due to changes to a json-file

Tags: javascript, npm, nodemon

I have a nodemon server running, but if I change a file with fs.writeFileSync nodemon restarts and the json-file loses its data.

I tried to prevent this by putting a ignore in the package.json

```
"nodemonConfig": {
  "ignore": ["*.json"]
}
```

This is not working. I think it could be because I installed nodemon global. Then I found another possibility to prevent this by creating a nodemon.json with:

```
{
    "ignore": ["*.json"]
}
```

but this is also not working. The third possibility was to write:

```
nodemon --ignore '[users.json]'
```

in the terminal. It could be that I wrote the line wrong or something else, but I am just not getting the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `nodemon` configuration within the `package.json` file, for example:

```
{
  "name": "label",
  "version": "0.0.1",
     

  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": ["*.json", "public/javascripts/*.js"]
  },


  "author": "@aqui",
  "license": "GPL-3.0"
}
```

The key must be `nodemonConfig`. Ignore rules can be specified as an array of globs or complete filenames

Or you can edit your `package.json` file to update the run scripts this way.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js --ignore *.json"
  },
```

Comment: OP described that adding ignore to nodemonConfig does not work for him and is interested only into `.json` files.

Comment: Yes, and he can try the 2nd option, changing the package.json file. My answer was for other users as well as for him on how to use nodemon ignore.

Comment: I think second option should work fine, just wanted to make sure you did not misread that question.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping. I now added the dev script to my packege.json and I tried to run `npm run dev`, but it just threw an error "no such file". Also there was no such a dev before. I know this from other projects, but I am not sure if I have to do it like this `npm run dev`.

Comment: @Copied what does your scripts part in the `package.json` look like?

Comment: My package.json file has generally the following scripts, which enable me to watch my files for typescript, sass compilations and running a server as well.

 "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"sass --watch ./style/sass:./style/css\" \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w", 
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  }

Comment: There was no script part. I just wrote nodemon server/server.js. Could it affect if I installed nodemon gloablly?

Comment: Is your server.js file under the `server` folder? `server/server.js` should be the server.js file path relative to your project root directory

Comment: I have a client folder in my project and a server folder. The server.js-file in the server.js is the main file in this folder. I start the server by writing nodemon server/server.js because I don't type cd server. My package.json had no script or nodemon dependency in it. It also had no nodemonConfig. `
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.4"
  }}`this was my whole package.json

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before running the project?

Comment: I think so.
`npm i express socket.io`
I think this was my installing in my server folder. Like I said the nodemon was globally installed.

Comment: You'd better run `npm init` first, and then copy the dependcies into the new package.json file and run `npm install`. Then you'll see the `script` tag in the package.json

Comment: Well, I found my problem. I couldn't run npm run dev, because i was not in  the server folder... xD. I tried to run npm run dev in the project folder. Now it is running if I run the command. But there is now no more website. But I think I'll get this by my self. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help! Just let me know in case you need any assistance. :)